# jQuery form redirects to action instead of performing an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a weird behaviour with an AJAX login form that is displayed inside a Bootstrap modal box.

80% of times I hit the enter button or click "Submit", an XHR request is sent to my application and everything works fine (I'm either redirected to the start page or I get the message that the username/password combination is wrong).

But in about 2 of 10 tests, no XHR request is fired but a normal request is fired and my browser redirects to the/displays the JSON response (e.g. `{"status":"FAILED","errors":[{"code":1222204027,"message":"Authentication failed!","severity":"Error","title":""}]}`).

```
function registerAjaxForm() {
    $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $('#login-form');
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(arr) {
                $('.alert').remove();
                $form.hide();
                $('.modal-body').append('<p align="center"><i class="icon-spin icon-spinner icon-4x muted"></i></p>');
            },
            error: function(data){
                $('.modal-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><h4 class="alert-heading">Oh snap! Your server took a nose dive!</h4>Internal Server error</div>');
                $('p .icon-spin').remove();
                $form.show(800, 'swing');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'OK') {
                    window.location = response.redirect;
                } else if (response.status === 'FAILED') {
                    var error;
                    for (error in response.errors) {
                        $('.modal-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>'+ response.errors[error].message +'</div>');
                    }
                    $('.control-group').addClass('error');
                    $('p .icon-spin').remove();
                    $form.show(800, 'swing');
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

(Reproducible at least in Chrome and Safari.)

I assume that somehow the submit event cannot be bound to the form. The HTML of the form is also loaded by AJAX but I wait with binding it until it is there:

```
$(function() {

    // Link Action to get Login Panel
    $('.login-panel').click(function(el) {
        el.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function(response){
            $('#modal-login').html(response).promise().done(function() {
                registerAjaxForm();
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Maybe it's just some stupid error but I cannot find it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: any reason to use deffered technique with jquery `html` method? I'm pretty sure it's synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this problem occasionally, the problem might be of your AJAX request is asynchronous. Set:

```
 async: false
```

in your ajax call and instead of

> e.preventDefault();

**EDIT:**
use:
 return false:

Comment: Only `return false;` will work as `preventDefault`. Use synchronous ajax is really bad idea.

Comment: Tommi says: "Use synchronous ajax is really bad idea." and you say "Yes, you are correct." But you suggested using async: false. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

when the html is dynamically loaded always use event delegation to attach events

```
$('body').on('submit','#login-form',function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $('#login-form');
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:$form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(arr) {
            $('.alert').remove();
            $form.hide();
            $('.modal-body').append('<p align="center"><i class="icon-spin icon-spinner icon-4x muted"></i></p>');
        },
        error: function(data){
            $('.modal-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><h4 class="alert-heading">Oh snap! Your server took a nose dive!</h4>Internal Server error</div>');
            $('p .icon-spin').remove();
            $form.show(800, 'swing');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'OK') {
                window.location = response.redirect;
            } else if (response.status === 'FAILED') {
                var error;
                for (error in response.errors) {
                    $('.modal-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>'+ response.errors[error].message +'</div>');
                }
                $('.control-group').addClass('error');
                $('p .icon-spin').remove();
                $form.show(800, 'swing');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

and i'm not sure about the content type you have used so i have changed that to `json` and data is missing in your call so i have added that. make a note of these changes.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This helps somehow, but generates a lot of requests. So if I hit submit it gets executed 3 times and I don't know why.

Comment: i think you are calling this piece of code multiple times. make sure you call it once.

Answer (score 0):

put an alert on the first line inside registerAjaxForm(), and see when the xhr fails if this function is called or not. If yes then you have to check your function else check why it was not called..